# How to show marker information into a tab

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup, markers

I have a lot of information that I want to show on a Leaflet Popup. For these type of markers (I have four different layers and each marker show different information) I have three elements:

[image]

- General description
- Images
- Video

But I want to show them as tabs inside the Popup. Something like these:

[image]

To add each icon I use these method:

```
    L.marker([20.683, -88.568], {icon: tiloIcon}).bindPopup('<p><strong><center>        Chichén Itzá</center></strong><br><strong>Cultura</strong><br />Maya <br/> <strong>Descripción</strong><br />Es uno de los sitios arqueológicos más importantes de la Península de Yucatán. Es la ciudad más impresionante del periodo Clásico maya y fue inscrita en la lista del Patrimonio de la Humanidad de la UNESCO.<br /><a href="http://superexample.com" target="_blank">Ver ficha completa</a></p>         <img src="emoji.png"  style="width:200px;">   <iframe width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kd8fBAaKU90" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').addTo(sitios),
```

Additionally, I want that the title tab disappear and show it at the top of the popup

**Do you know any way to put the information on tabs?**

Answer (score 4):

Before you create your markers, create a variable that will hold your **popup tabs content**, e.g.:

CSS:

```
  .info {
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:260px;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    border-radius:2px;
    }
    .info .item {
      display:block;
      border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
      padding:10px;
      text-decoration:none;
      }
      .info .item small { color:#888; }
      .info .item:hover,
      .info .item.active { background:#f8f8f8; }
      .info .item:last-child { border-bottom:none; }

.leaflet-popup-content {
  width:240px;    
  }

.tabs {
    position:relative;
    min-height:200px;
    clear:both;
    margin:25px 0;
}
.tab {
    float:left;
    display: none;
}
.tab:first-of-type {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tabs-link {
    position: relative;
    top: -14px;
    height: 20px;
    left: -40px;
}
.tab-link {
    background:#eee;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left:-1px;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    left:1px;
    top:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tab-link {
    background:#f8f8f8;
}
.content {
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:28px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.tab:target {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
var content = '<div class="tabs">' +

            '<div class="tab" id="tab-1">' +
            '<div class="content">' +
            '<b>Tab 1 content</b>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +

            '<div class="tab" id="tab-2">' +
            '<div class="content">' +
            '<b>Tab 2 content</b>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
    
            '<div class="tab" id="tab-3">' +
            '<div class="content">' +
            '<b>Tab 3 content</b>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
    
            '<ul class="tabs-link">' +
            '<li class="tab-link"> <a href="#tab-1"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>' +
            '<li class="tab-link"> <a href="#tab-2"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>' +
            '<li class="tab-link"> <a href="#tab-3"><span>Tab 3</span></a></li>' +
            '</ul>' +
        '</div>';
```

Then bind that content to your marker **`bindPopup(content)`**:

```
 L.marker([20.683, -88.568], {icon: tiloIcon}).bindPopup(content);
```

Working **example** on codepen: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/LxwYrY (example is with polygons, but binding popup method works the same)

Comment: I am trying the solution proposed by deevee but it did not work for me as it is in the example.

Comment: @BárbaraDuarte If you have problems implementing the answer, post it as a new question, together with the code you have tried.

Comment: I try the code provided by deevee. However it did not work for me.